# Cannot Terminate While Loop in Killed Thread

Tags: python, multithreading

The point of my script is to have one function called stopper send a terminate thread event to the function go_to, once it reaches a certain time.

Currently, the event is triggered, the thread supposedly closed, and stopper is ended. But go_to continues to print to the command line.

I can't figure out how to stop it correctly.

```
import threading
import time

class Stop_Check(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.thread1Stop = threading.Event()

    def stopper(self):
        t = 0
        while True:
            t = t + 1
            time.sleep(1.0)
            if t == 3 :
                self.thread1Stop.set()
                break
            else :
                print("I'm still going...")
                time.sleep(1.0)
                continue
        print("terminated")

    def go_to(self):
        while (not self.thread1Stop.is_set()):
            print("I am working!")
            time.sleep(1.0)

    def main(self):
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.go_to)
        t1.start()
        self.stopper()
        time.sleep(5.0)

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    sc = Stop_Check()
    sc.main()
```

Comment: I am running Python 3.7.1 and ran your code but I am unable to reproduce your problem. Here is the output that I got:I am working!
I'm still going...
I am working!
I am working!
I'm still going...
I am working!
I am working!
terminated.                            Which python version are you using?

Comment: I did find a problem that you were describing if I interrupted the program before it finishes (by pressing ctrl-c). Is that the problem you are having or is it different? If it is I will put it as an answer.

Comment: @Steven Thanks for trying it! I am running Python 3.6.4 (in anaconda), but it is being run inside Atom. What you are seeing is the correct functionality. I do not ctrl-c out of it early, but that is an interesting find. Mine continually prints "I am working!" until I force quit out of the program.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running the script in the terminal, outside of the software called Atom. Now it terminates as expected. Thanks to @Steven for confirming it works! Still not sure why this behavior was happening.